# Reliable upload to APS/ACC/Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

All upload examples I can find only handle the happy path for a upload and demonstrate uploading of a single file. The reality of uploading to ACC is a bunch of `502 BadGateway` and `429 Too Many Requests` responses which have to be handled/retried.

I have a upload impl. using `Polly` but it just doesn't work reliably. It seems APS is simply terminating all connections for a given client once a error condition (502, 429, etc.) is encountered and I have a hard time catching the correct exceptions and retrying requests.

Reproducing this issue is straightforward: upload 500+ mostly empty text files to ACC (try parallel upload if you feel adventurous). Unfortunately this problem will also occur randomly when uploading ~10 files.

Did anyone figure out how to reliably upload files to ACC using signed S3 uploads?

This problem is especially annoying for my use-case, since I want to upload a bunch of files at the end of a Design Automation run. When the upload fails I have to restart the complete operation, wasting even more compute. I'm now considering uploading to some other S3 compatible storage.

Example of a failed upload in Design Automation:

```
... successfully uploaded a couple of files
[09/25/2023 11:37:33] [11:37:33 DBG] Http request POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.emea.2/objects/myfile.pdf/signeds3upload 
[09/25/2023 11:37:33] [11:37:33 WRN] Retry after Transient Error BadGateway https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.emea.2/myfile.pdf/signeds3upload
[09/25/2023 11:38:33] [11:38:33 WRN] Retry after Timeout A task was canceled.
[09/25/2023 11:38:43] [11:38:43 WRN] Retry after Timeout A task was canceled.
[09/25/2023 11:38:53] [11:38:53 WRN] Retry after Timeout A task was canceled.
[09/25/2023 11:39:03] [11:39:03 WRN] Retry after Timeout A task was canceled.
[09/25/2023 11:39:13] System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
[09/25/2023 11:39:13]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[09/25/2023 11:39:13]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
... more stacktrace
[09/25/2023 11:39:14] [11:39:14 INF] Shutdown
[09/25/2023 11:39:17] RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
[09/25/2023 11:39:17] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[09/25/2023 11:39:17] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
```

ps. I forgot to mention another beautiful edge case: If you want to create a new file you have to call `CreateVersion`, when updating a file `UpdateVersion`. When uploading many files `CreateVersion` will sometimes fail, but if you retry you get `409 Conflict`. So I guess it didn't actually fail? ‍♂️

Comment: If you are using Design Automation this should work for you.
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/new-feature-support-direct-s3-migration-inputoutput-files-design-automation

Comment: Thanks for info. Unfortunately I can't use that since I would need to know all filenames upfront, which I don't. I'm generating PDFs from Revit Views, which can be an arbitrary amount. Quote "Design Automation will extend the provided valid access token if it is expired.": how is this possible, hidden refresh token? CVE incoming?

Comment: Will packaging them into a zip and uploading to one location work?

Comment: I like the pragmatic approach. Zipping the files would allow me to use the built-in upload functions (as I would know the filename) and would in general make my usage of the api much more reliable (as I would simply call it less). The only piece missing is the unzip operation, since I want to enable my users to download each file separately.

Comment: You would have to implement a service that enables people to get files out of the uploaded zip. Here is a blog post on how to do that without having to download the whole zip: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/revit-cloud-worksharing-fast-extraction-revit-zip-files-partials

Comment: For a .net implementation of the blog post that Adam pointed out, you can find that here: https://github.com/yiskang/aps-utility-service-dotnet/blob/master/Autodesk.Aps/Controllers/ExtractController.cs#L178 and https://github.com/yiskang/aps-utility-service-dotnet/blob/master/Autodesk.Aps/Controllers/ExtractController.cs#L205, but I don't implement the features for uploading files to BIM360/ACC Docs.

Comment: Range-requesting a zip like that is neat. Thanks guys for constructing a very nice workaround for my issue.